# Spring Boot Firebase JsonWriter

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, firebase-realtime-database

I have this very simple Spring boot application with following dependencies.

```
compile(
    "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
    "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest",
    "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor",
    "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:2.1.3",
    "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:2.1.3",
    "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3",
    "com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.5.0"
)
```

I'm simply trying to put a POJO on to my realtime firebase database.

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
db.reference.setValue(
    SomePojo().apply {
        name = ""
        someOtherProp = "Some other value"
    },
    { err, _ ->
        println("error=$err")
    })
```

However in the logs I can see something is going wrong inside the lib.

```
2017-11-17 15:18:08.376  INFO 1377 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-11-17 15:18:08.385  INFO 1377 --- [           main] be.topradio.metadata.AppKt               : Started AppKt in 19.051 seconds (JVM running for 19.615)
2017-11-17 15:18:08.908 ERROR 1377 --- [eDatabaseWorker] c.google.firebase.database.core.RunLoop  : Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (5.5.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONStringer.object()Lorg/json/JSONWriter;
    at com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJsonValue(JsonMapper.java:72) ~[firebase-admin-5.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJsonValue(JsonMapper.java:61) ~[firebase-admin-5.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJson(JsonMapper.java:41) ~[firebase-admin-5.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.database.util.GAuthToken.serializeToString(GAuthToken.java:67) ~[firebase-admin-5.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.JvmAuthTokenProvider.wrapOAuthToken(JvmAuthTokenProvider.java:86) ~[firebase-admin-5.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.JvmAuthTokenProvider.getToken(JvmAuthTokenProvider.java:66) ~[firebase-admin-5.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context$1.getToken(Context.java:63) ~[firebase-admin-5.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$1.run(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:481) ~[firebase-admin-5.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.firebase.database.connection.util.RetryHelper$1.run(RetryHelper.java:93) ~[firebase-admin-5.5.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

I was about to get rid of this error by excluding a dependency pulled in by Spring Boot's configuration processor:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor') {
       exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google'
}
```

Additionally (though I did not see this error anymore), I believe it should be excluded on Spring Boot's starter test dependency as well.

```
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
       exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google'
}
```

## How I found this

From [StackOverflow question you visited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651768/firebase-in-spring-boot-gives-error-during-initalization), I began looking into potential issue with class JSONStringer in package 'org.json'. So I was thinking a version conflict of a dependency that depended on 'org.json'

Running `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency org.json`, I received:

```
org.json:json:20160810 -> 20140107
+--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:1.7.0
|    +--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.7.0
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.5.0
|    |         \--- compile
|    +--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.25.0-beta
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.5.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-http:1.7.0
|    |    +--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.7.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.25.0-beta (*)
|    \--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:1.7.0
|         \--- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.25.0-beta (*)
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.5.0 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

so only the google dependencies were using this package. I suspected that the issue wasn't a version conflict in the google dependecies, so I looked for conflicts that Spring may have with the org.json pacakage.

Google search for 'Spring boot org.json' led me to a [Github issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651768/firebase-in-spring-boot-gives-error-during-initalization) about conflicts with json library. The issue mentioned that for spring-boot-starter-test since "org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.4.0 is required, exclude com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1."

From that, I ran: `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency 'com.vaadin.external.google' which referenced 'spring-boot-configuration-processor'.