# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.putOnce(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/json/JSONObject;

Tags: java, json, firebase

I have faced an Error

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

> org.json.JSONObject.putOnce(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/json/JSONObject;
>       at org.json.JSONWriter.key(JSONWriter.java:208)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJsonValue(JsonMapper.java:76)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJsonValue(JsonMapper.java:61)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper.serializeJson(JsonMapper.java:41)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.util.GAuthToken.serializeToString(GAuthToken.java:67)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.core.JvmAuthTokenProvider.wrapOAuthToken(JvmAuthTokenProvider.java:86)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.core.JvmAuthTokenProvider.getToken(JvmAuthTokenProvider.java:66)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context$1.getToken(Context.java:62)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$1.run(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:490)
>       at com.google.firebase.database.connection.util.RetryHelper$1.run(RetryHelper.java:93)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: What a question is this? It would be nice to have some context

Comment: Seems you have imported the project and did not add the third party libraries (jar).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a common dependency conflict when using Firebase's Admin SDK and Spring. The discussion is [here](https://github.com/tdunning/open-json/issues/11), and possible solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651768/firebase-in-spring-boot-gives-error-during-initalization).

I have test the solution and it works but I am checking about possible side effects.

Answer (score -1):

According to [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html):

> "NoSuchMethodError" Thrown if an application tries to call a specified
>   method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no
>   longer has a definition of that method.

So, look at the stack trace:

- If the exception appears when youre calling a method from library - you have not included its jar in build.
- If it happens when youre calling your own method - make sure the class files that you are actually running are updated when you compile

But first of all - try to clean and build (clean install in mvn)

Comment: Other possibility could be to have compiled code with a specific version of the library and use a different library version (with a change on the used method) at run time.

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález thats basically first bullet